# Alerts about activity on associated accounts

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, answers, linked-accounts

I just thought of this feature.
I just asked a question on stackoverflow, and started browsing superuser. If someone answer me on stackoverflow, would'nt it be nice if I had the orange top bar rolling down on superuser telling me that someone answered me on Stackoverflow?
That would add value to associating accounts as well I think.

Thoughts?

Comment: see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6033/trilogy-portal-community-collaboration

Comment: the first answer is what I mean yes, but not the question itself! Merging the 3 websites is not what I am suggesting at all. They are fine split the way they are in my opinion.

Comment: The exact dupe is http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6031, but was closed itself as a dupe of the one I gave above.

Comment: okay, Then as I mentioned in the comments, I suck at searching. :)
thanks

Comment: well, I can't delete the question, neither close it I think

Comment: No need to delete; this is one of those cases where having the dupe around might be really helpful. It increases the chance that someone with the same question finds the relevant info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The plan is to have a common notification page that pulls together all your notifications from throughout the network. Then we can turn on some kind of envelope icon when there's something new in the notification page.

Comment: Any idea on when this will be implemented?

Comment: I think it's supposed to be ready in about six to eight weeks.

Comment: So that's just around the corner :) great! for instance I would have seen this answer earlier if we had this feature. Awesome. I really think it is going to enhance the user involvement on the multiple platforms!

Answer (score 3):

The downside to this is that it has the potential to add a lot of **noise**. Maybe shifting gears is a good thing; being constantly distracted by actions on another site can break up the flow.

If you really want to be notified, you could try a browser plugin, such as [the excellent extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/djioipahfnmmhddmnanoicecpnfomned?hl=en) for Chrome made by [Sam Hasler](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38544/stack-overflow-notifier-chrome-extension).

Comment: hm, that's true when you have a lot of activity going on your accounts. Could still be possible to disable it though. but helpful answer :)

Comment: +1 for the chrome plugin! :)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose as an extension to the alert, some kind of tilogy dashboard consolidating activity across all sites would be a natural step.  And before you know where you are everyone could have a consolidated reputation score.

Although I can't believe that it hasn't been suggested before.

Comment: well it seems that it hasn't, or I suck at searching, which is highly probable as well.

Comment: @Stephane I meant I was assuming what I was saying would have been suggested before - I was assuming that you had checked your question!

Comment: I did but not enough obviously :)

Answer (score 0):

See details at

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/network-central-stackexchange-com/

or click the StackExchange logo in the upper left hand corner of any SE 2.0 site..