# More closely link the “meta-xyz” sites with the xyz sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51

When I posted one question to the webapp-meta site, I did not see the responses for a long time, as there is nothing on the webapp site to say I have a response on the meta site.

This needs to be sorted out, otherwise the Meta sites will be a lot less effective.

Please note I think a “smaller” solution is needed than: "[Alerts about activity on associated accoun](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46441/alerts-about-activity-on-associated-accounts)ts"

Answer (score 7):

I quite agree with that. If the Meta and "parent sites" are closely linked, especially with reputation, it would be nice if getting a notification about activity on Meta.

It doesn't have to be a complete notification with details, just a "there are notifications pending on Meta", inviting to switch to it.

Comment: Just putting envelope (with meta has notifications/answers)  next to the link to the related Meta site may be all that is needed.

Comment: @Ian - hmm, good idea.