# Show Meta notifications on parent site

Tags: feature-request, notifications, per-site-meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [More closely link the “meta-xyz” sites with the xyz sites.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58574/more-closely-link-the-meta-xyz-sites-with-the-xyz-sites)

With all these wonderful new StackExchange sites, I find I'm not as vigilant about participating in Meta as I was when I only visited one or two.

Now that the meta-sites are more integrated with the parent sites, I think it would be nice to see some notification on the parent site when you have responses/notifications on the associated Meta site. It could be as simple as having the a separate envelope icon to light up for Meta-notifications.

Anyone with me?

Comment: I just use the [chrome notifier](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38544/stack-overflow-notifier-chrome-extension)  You can add whatever site you like.

Comment: Yes, the problem are that the fav icons are all the same for all the betas, which is an inconvenience @Zoredache

Comment: ^ the problem *is*

Comment: @Juan, the problem is, as the availability of public and private betas increase, so does my consumption of Ritalin. Enough is enough, please, dear God .. Nooooooooooo!

Comment: possible duplicate: [More closely link the “meta-xyz” sites with the xyz sites.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58574/more-closely-link-the-meta-xyz-sites-with-the-xyz-sites).

Comment: Since this was closed as a dupe, I'm not going to bother bumping it with `[status-completed]`, but [it is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46441/alerts-about-activity-on-associated-accounts).

Answer (score 0):

I visit meta quite often, so I don't find it necessary.

Furthermore, I think it would bother me, diverting my focus from the parent site when I'm at the parent site.

I like having them separated, and even though it's highly encouraged, it's not mandatory to participate in meta.
I would recommend visiting meta more.

Comment: Same here, but now I have FIVE meta-sites to keep track of. I don't visit all those dail.

Comment: I visit *this* meta often, but I tend to forget about it on the other sites

Comment: Well, I'm only committed to only [one other site](http://gaming.stackexchange.com) currently so perhaps I'm not the most common example...

Comment: Don't forget about Super User and Server Fault, which *also* have their own meta sites - it's a LOT of meta