# Show new Meta questions in top bar on smaller SE sites

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, stackexchange-2.0, per-site-meta

Younger SE sites's Meta areas seem relatively little frequented, and the idea of also checking the meta sites  may not be obvious to every participant. More meta participation (if just for up- or downvoting feature requests) is a good thing, as it helps shape the site especially in its early stages.

Would it be a good idea to notify users on the main site of new meta questions that have come up since their last login?

Like so:

[image]

or so:

[image]

Related, but not identical: [Show Meta notifications on parent site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58674/show-meta-notifications-on-parent-site)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a great idea, though I wonder if it might be a bit obnoxious.

We absolutely want to **make sure people *know about* meta** but participating there is completely optional. Putting a BIG RED INDICATOR seems a bit like crying wolf, a disproportionately nuclear solution to the "gee, it would be nice if avid users visited meta" problem.

Comment: Yeah. The main motivation for this is to prevent things like "What! Our site got merged with PigSkinning.SE and we weren't told about it?" - maybe  notification should be limited to discussions on such fundamental issues so all users have a chance to see and vote on them. Not sure about what such a "important discussion" indicator could be, though.

Comment: @pekka this change would also teach users to ignore topbar indicators which would be *very very VERY **VERY** bad*.

Comment: that is true. It's a downside strong enough to make the suggestion not viable in the presented form

Comment: @pekka BUT! We could do it at the bottom, as we do with the blog..?

Comment: mmm, nice idea! Maybe for new questions that surpass a certain vote threshold to catch only the hot, important ones?

Answer (score 3):

On metas with low enough activity, all questions will get some air time in the "Visit Meta" sidebar section.

Comment: Ah, hadn't  thought of that. Good point.